# CSV reading first line, editing it and then store into database - PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm new with php and I am currently working on a project which involve of csv. I do not have any past experience of writing a script to read csv files. So please do not ignore my post and do excuse me.

Summary: The task require me to read a CSV file with php script, rename the 1st line (Title, and insert into database).

I am not very familiar with php code, so I would appreciate any help, and this is what I would like to do.

Example data of the CSV File

```
Name Contact ID Email Address Status
Alice 0134222 21 alice@gmail.com 92 alice st available
claire 013423 24 claire@gmail.com 1 young st avail
victor 023429 31 victor@gmail.com 15/8 johnson st not available
```

create a function that reads a CSV file.

```
function parse_csvdata($filename) {
  //read the first line of the csv file only (the title)
  //rename the title to User_Name, User_Contact, User_ID (instead of Name, Contact, ID)

  //temporary store it in an array as TITLE

  //read the rest of the data (after the first line)
  //check the data in the title column. I want to change all avail to Available

  then create a new CSV out of this
}
```

I already finish the script to parse csv files into mysql. But I just dunno how to rename/reformat the csv data. Please help me, thanks in advance,

Comment: You should the code you have.

Comment: Is your problem really that the column names in the CSV don't match your database tables' column names? If so, I'd just create a lookup array as a config that maps the names in your CSV to your table column names.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your parsing entails, but i recommend using [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv) for parsing. How you manipulate and push back to a database is up to you.

[`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) is also useful for writing back to the file. Both doc pages have examples of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the entire code to parse and get the values into an array.You can use [ParseCSV](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) library to do it. You can take the values to an array and manipulate it.